# How to setup/install in Rails 4 the i18n-js for translations in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

For the javascripts translations in Rails 4 I used the following [library](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js).
I did:

Gemfile:

```
gem "i18n-js", ">= 3.0.0.rc11"
```

In `assets/javascripts/application.rb`:

```
//= require i18n/translations
```

and finally I worked on the `config/locales/en.yml` data

Example:

```
en:
  save: 
    text1: value1
  independency:
    text2: value2
```

In the view I used this for the translations, as in Rails.

```
series: [{
          name: '',    
          data: [ 
              ["<%=t 'independency.text1' %>", independency], 
              ["<%=t 'save.text2' %>", 100-independency],                
           ]          
      }]
```

The thing is that I have to run this command `rake i18n:js:export` after doing any change in the translation file that involved the javascript part.

Moreover, the next day after starting the PC and opening again my application (localhost:3000) the javascript translations did not work at all. I had to run again the command `rake i18n:js:export`.

Is there any option to avoid executing this command every time? For me is difficult to understand the documentation.